# Highchart Color and lineWidth options don't work

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, highcharts

I draw a line graph with highcharts / AngularJS.
Here is JSfiddle link.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {..})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Texas101/pL0at45o/

As you can see, I set linewidth and color for every series, and it works correctly.

I've used the same code in my application, but linewidth and color options are not working.
Here is the image of the graph on my application.
[image]

As you can see, lineWidth and color options are not working, and automatically added _colorIndex option. It seems these colors are automatically allocated to these series.
I want to fix this problem.

Is this something you'd faced before? Why options are not working and colors / lineWidths are automatically allocated? Is there any solution to fix this problem?

Comment: The JSFiddle doesn't look like it's working to me. Every line is red.

Comment: @dom_ahdigital - Yes. JSfiddle is working for me.But the same code is not working in my application. lineWidth and color options are not working.
So I am asking you if you faced this before.

Comment: So in your application, you want all lines in the series to be red like in your Fiddle?

Comment: Yes. I want to control line color/line width, but it seems I can't control it.

Comment: @Deimos620 What `Highcharts` version are you using in your application?

Comment: I am using 6.0.3, the latest version (2017.11.17)

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue in this fiddle but everything seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/fethLLxj/ Please provide some live example of this problem.

Comment: @KamilKulig- Yeah. It's completely same with the code snippet in my application. As you can see it works in jsfiddle but not in my application.
I use AngularJS theme which uses Highcharts. I am thinking that any global settings which I didn't find out are affecting to this.
Does highcharts have any global settings?